# What we can use "there" or "over there"

Tags: vocabulary

When we can use word "there" and when "over there"? I could not find the answer in the dictionary.Thanks

Comment: You need to provide us with examples and a context.

Comment: *There* is used to indicate a distance farther than *here*.  *Over there* usually means that one would have to move or travel (hint: *over* some distance) to get there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Over there" is further than "there" and "there" is further than "here."

"Here" usually means "at one's feet" or "the place where one is at." You do not have to move to get "here." You are already "here."

If you want to go to somewhere else, that place is "there." And you need to go "there" to be "there."

If you are in the US Army, you can go "[over there](http://youtu.be/BYV044H5muI?t=1m32s)" (over the ocean) to fight the enemy.

As this World War I-era song shows, "over there" refers to a long distance. But it does not have to be so far as "over to another country" or "abroad."

"Over there" means somewhere out of reach. You need to stand up and move "over there" to get some object that is "over there" from where you are. In other words, "over there" can be "across the room", "across the street", or "across the ocean." It is a relatively far distance as compared to "there."

Answer (score 2):

There are two words *there*. I think the Original Poster is asking about the preposition *there* (some people think it's an adverb). This word tells us about a location or goal. In other words it means something like *(in) that place*. Or, if we use a verb which indicates movement, it  means something like *to that place* or *towards that place*. Compare:

- He just sat there. (Location - in that place)
- He went there. (Goal - to that place)

We sometimes need extra help to show the listener the place that we are talking about being in or going to. We might point, for example. If the place is not very close, we can say *over there*. This helps guide the listener to a location a bit further away than they might expect.

The preposition *there* is a different word from the pronoun *there*. The pronoun *there* does not have any meaning. We use it in sentences which show that something exists:

- We need to stop.
- Why?
- There's a problem.

The word *there* in the sentence above is not talking about a location. The sentence just means "*A problem exists*". In this sentence the word *there* has no meaning at all.

Comment: *"**There** was a man sitting **over there** by that **there** tree stump"*, and so, how do them "there" and "over there" all differ from each other? :D

Comment: @F.E. Hmmm, not sure. Maybe you could write one of your mega-posts on this interesting question? :D

Comment: "that there" is non-standard. See https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/this-here-that-there/