# What meaning does the word “over” add?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does "over" word add any additional meaning to the below statement?

> Your room is on the first floor. Take the lift. It's **over** there.

Does the meaning of the sentence change?

> Your room is on the first floor. Take the lift. It's there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What we can use "there" or "over there"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54565/what-we-can-use-there-or-over-there)

Comment: @user178049: You're pointing the questioner to a closed question.

Comment: @TRomano Actually, I stated in my comment that the question has been closed. But it seems like it was edited. But, I wonder why not, the question is accessible and has good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Over there" refers to a horizontal distance.  It doesn't make sense with the vertical, as in your example of which floor something is on.

**over** in "over there" refers to the fact that there is  *some (horizontal) distance between* the speaker's location and the location he is referring to, or between your location and the location he is referring to.

But the distance is relative to the context. The location could be across the room or across the county or across the river, etc.

> I was in New Jersey last week.
>   --What were you doing over there?  (across the river)
>
> Have you seen the newspaper?
>   --It's on the table over there.  (across the room)